# Method to generate "_ _ _ " only returns "_ "

Tags: java, methods

I have problem with my method. I need the output of the method which I call from main class print me this:

Need this output:   _ _ _ _ _

I know I could put the static method of System in the loop, but this is not the solution I want. I need this to print this output from a method in the main class.

```
    // This is my method which I made in my class

    public String wordRows(int count){

        // inicializace proměnné v charu
        String r = "_";
        String space = " ";
        String spaceR = "";
        for( int i = 0; i <= count; i++){
            //System.out.print(r + space);
             spaceR = r + space;
        }

        return spaceR;

       }

       // Declaration of method in main class

       public class TestedProjectOfGuessword {

       /**
       * @param args the command line arguments
       */
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO code application logic here
       Rows rows = new Rows();

       System.out.println(rows.wordRows(8))
```

Comment: Well, what *is* the problem? (Hint: the code is not using the *previous* value of `spaceR` in the loop, which is trivial to see once adding the actual output to the question - see my title update.)

Comment: The problem is that I need to get this output : " _ _ _ _ _ " through the loop in spaceR and then print it through the main class.

Comment: Can you tag what language this is?  Guessing java.

Comment: Once again, consider the *actual* output.. this can tell a good bit about the source of the problem.

Comment: `spaceR = r + space;` is the problem line, you rewrite spaceR each time..

Comment: Yes it is Java. When I run it I get just: "_" and I need to get : _ _ _ _

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for( int i = 0; i <= count; i++){
            //System.out.print(r + space);
             spaceR += r + space;
        }
```

The problem is that you are assigning spaceR each time in the loop, not appending.
You show build your string in each loop iteration by adding a new r + space, not start from zero and only make one r + space.

Anyway, use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of String, and use its `append` method.

EDIT: Please note if you start your loop at 0 and stop when is `<= count`, you will have `count + 1` elements. if you only want count elements, stop the loop condition with `i < count`

Answer (score 1):

You need to append to spaceR

```
spaceR = spaceR + r + space;
```